# Mock a connection class in pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, rabbitmq, kombu

I have a class which inherits from `kombu.ConsumerProducerMixin` which I would like to test without an actual rabbitmq service running.

```
class Aggregator(ConsumerProducerMixin):

    def __init__(self, broker_url):
        exchange_name = 'chargers'
        self.status = 0
        self.connection = Connection(broker_url)
        ...
```

In my test file I did the following:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

from aggregator import Aggregator

@patch('kombu.connection.Connection')
def test_on_request(conn_mock):

    agg = Aggregator('localhost')
    m = Message("", {"action": "start"}, content_type="application/json")
```

Stepping into the `Aggregator.__init__` with the debugger, I see that `connection` is still not patched to be a `Mock` instance:

```
(Pdb) self.connection
<Connection: amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672// at 0x7fc8b7f636d8>
(Pdb) Connection
<class 'kombu.connection.Connection'>
```

My question is how do I properly patch connection such that I don't need rabbitmq to run the tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, The [docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.object) state the following:

> patch() works by (temporarily) changing the object that a name points
>   to with another one. There can be many names pointing to any
>   individual object, so for patching to work you must ensure that you
>   patch the name used by the system under test.
>
> The basic principle is that you patch where an object is looked up,
>   which is not necessarily the same place as where it is defined. A
>   couple of examples will help to clarify this.

Hence, the solution:

```
@patch('aggregator.aggregator.Connection')
def test_on_request(mock_connect):
    agg = Aggregator('localhost')
```